# Azure data factory pipeline not update using arm

Tags: pipeline, azure-data-factory, azure-resource-manager

I've already publish one of my azure data factory pipeline using arm template. Now in one of the sink blob storage file path which I've updated in my template and re-deploy  it in same pipeline using 'New-AzResourceGroupDeployment'.

But here my file path is not getting updated.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please use the incremental mode of `New-AzResourceGroupDeployment` to update the existing properties.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azresourcegroupdeployment?view=azps-2.8.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/deployment-modes#incremental-mode